# Shell script regex rename

Tags: regex, shell

Hi I am trying to rename 1000 of files from

`xyzPL 7-1-16 page1+2(1).xlsx` into `7-1-16.xlsx`

`xyzPL 12-1-16 page1+2(1).xls` into `12-1-16.xls`

`xyzPL 12-10-16 page1+2(1).xls` into `12-10-16.xls`

So far I have following for loop

```
for in *.xls; do echo mv "$f" "${f/_*_/_}"; done
```

What the expression should I put for `${f/_*_/_}`

Thank you!

Comment: Do you really want to rename the two `.xls` files as `.xlsx` files?

Comment: Nice catch! Too much copy and paste ill edit.

Comment: Shell regular expressions (globbing) are crude.  You might have enough power with `shopt -s extglob` but I'm not sure.  I'd not want to deal with that pattern using shell.  Have at it if you really want to, but it will be a headache.

Comment: I guess I am much better off using simple Java to rename my files : (

Comment: Whatever takes your fancy and gets the job done for you.  One-off, Java won't be a problem.  I'd rather use Perl than Java on a routine basis, and I've had a Perl-based rename around since the 1st Edition of the Camel Book (according to my VCS, I saved the first version in January 1992).

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest looking into the `rename` (or, on some platforms, `prename`) facility.

It's not part of `bash` itself but should be available in all the regular distros.

It allows Perl regular expressions to be used to rename files and will almost certainly be a good sight quicker than a `bash`-based `for` loop.

By way of example, the following command should handle the three cases you've shown:

```
rename -n 's/^xyzPL (\d+-\d+-\d+).?*\.(xl‌​sx?)$/$1.$2/' xyzPL*.xls xyzPL*.xlsx
```

It captures the `n-n-n` bit into `$1` and the file extension into `$2` and then performs a simple (as if *anything* in Perl could be considered simple) substitution.

Note particularly the `-n` flag, this will print out what the command will do without actually doing it. It's *very* useful for checking what will happen before actually doing it.

Once you're satisfied it won't screw up everything, just run it again without the `-n`. Of course, being the paranoid type, I'd tend to back up the entire directory anyway.

Comment: this rename cannot be done with simple for loop? I am not experienced in shell so I am not sure what shell can do! Thank you

Comment: As in `rename 's/^xyzPL (\d+-\d+-\d+).?*(.xlsx?)$/$1.$2/' xyz*.xls*`.

Comment: @Zanko, it probably can be done, the same way you could eventually get a rabid monkey to cut down a Karri tree with a haddock :-) Me, I'd prefer to use the best tool for the job.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler where should I put that expression? Thank you for your help!

Comment: That's the complete command.  Replace the for loop with the single `rename` command.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you! Do I need additional package or library? I am running Mac OS terminal and it say `./shell.sh: line 1: rename: command not found`

Comment: You have to find it — I keep my copy in `$HOME/bin`, but it isn't on a Mac by default.

Comment: @Zanko, you can go and get the Homebrew package manager at which point it's a simple `brew install rename`.

Comment: Note the slight tweak to the regex in my previous comment; I'm accidentally putting two dots before the xls or xlsx suffix.  It should be: `rename 's/^xyzPL (\d+-\d+-\d+).?*\.(xl‌​sx?)$/$1.$2/' xyz*.xls*`

Answer (score 0):

A slightly souped-up version of the Perl-based `rename` command, originally from the 1st Edition of the Camel Book (Programming in Perl, by Larry Wall).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
#
# @(#)$Id: rename.pl,v 1.8 2011/06/03 22:30:22 jleffler Exp $
#
# Rename files using a Perl substitute or transliterate command

use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Std;

my(%opts);
my($usage) = "Usage: $0 [-fnxV] perlexpr [filenames]\n";
my($force) = 0;
my($noexc) = 0;
my($trace) = 0;

die $usage unless getopts('fnxV', \%opts);

if ($opts{V})
{
    printf "%s\n", q'RENAME Version $Revision: 1.8 $ ($Date: 2011/06/03 22:30:22 $)';
    exit 0;
}
$force = 1 if ($opts{f});
$noexc = 1 if ($opts{n});
$trace = 1 if ($opts{x});

my($op) = shift;
die $usage unless defined $op;

if (!@ARGV) {
    @ARGV = <STDIN>;
    chop(@ARGV);
}

for (@ARGV)
{
    if (-e $_ || -l $_)
    {
        my($was) = $_;
        eval $op;
        die $@ if $@;
        next if ($was eq $_);
        if ($force == 0 && -f $_)
        {
            print STDERR "rename failed: $was - $_ exists\n";
        }
        else
        {
            print "+ $was --> $_\n" if $trace;
            print STDERR "rename failed: $was - $!\n"
                unless ($noexc || rename($was, $_));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        print STDERR "$_ - $!\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using `rename` utility you can do this in pure BASH:

```
for file in *.xls*; do
    f="${file#* }"
    mv "$file" "${f/ *./.}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a subshell with the file name piped to awk...

```
$(echo "$f" | awk -F '[ .]' '{ print $2 "." $4 }')
```